# Popover message contains latex do not show it as math equation in kableExtra table

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, popover, kableextra

Here I give a reproducible example in RMarkdown.

````
---
title: "A reproducible example in rmarkdown"
output: html_document
---

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
</script>

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

df = tibble(
  position = c("top", "bottom"),
  latex = c("$x=1$", "$x=2$"),
  pop = cell_spec(
    paste("Math", latex),
    popover = spec_popover(
      content = latex, 
      title = NULL,
      position = position
    )
  ),
) %>% 
  select(-latex)
df %>% kbl(escape = F)
```
````

The popover message shows the row latex code as `$x=1$` and `$x=2$`, but not as latex math equation. How could one get the equations typeset as math equations?

Comment: According to [kable](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html) documentation, the generating `latex` language can be given as an argument: `knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), "latex")`. According to `kbl` wrapper function of `knitr:kable`, you can specify `kbl(...,format="latex")`.

Comment: But it doesn't work though. What I want is that table in html doc shows the popover message as latex math equation. So the message should be wrap with <span> and <script> related to latex generation such as <script type = "math/tex>$x=1$<script> to get it.